# I want to perform click action on button present under "svg" layout using selenium library

Tags: java, selenium, svg, selenium-webdriver

I want to perform click action on a button present under `.svg` layout using Selenium (Java bindings).

For example, I want to click on the button element, but every time I try to find an element by **xpath**, I get exception `enable to locate element

I read that with Selenium its tricky to click on element present under the `.svg`.

Is there anybody who knows a solution because, I haven't found a suitable solution on the net by myself.

Find below HTML code look likes this way:
[image]

**My code:**

```
List <WebElement> frame1=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'-06636000002Pb2L')]"));
System.out.println(frame1.size());
System.out.println(frame1.get(0).getAttribute("title"));
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
ElementaryOperations.Sleep(3000);
System.out.println("New relation frame found");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#newrel")).click();
```

After switching to frame successfully, I am not able to click on the element present under the SVG layout. Please refer to the attached screen shot(**[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNim3.jpg)**)

Comment: afaiac you have to be more specific about your development environment and what you have tried already giving code examples. You could also give selenium IDE a try. It can calculate xpath specifier for you.

Comment: @Ashvin Can you consider the following points: 1. Being specific about the Selenium binding you are using because in the Question Description you mentioned `Selenium (Java bindings)` but the error stacktrace says `OpenQA.Selenium` which is of C# Selenium binding. 2. You need to showcase your entire research in-order to enable the SO volunteers to concentrate on the specific issue. 3. There is nothing `tricky` to locate a `svg` element. Its pure logic. 4. Consider updating the relevant HTML DOM of the `svg` element in the Question area for further analysis. Thanks

Comment: I am also getting this exceptin for SVG element : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <text x="13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" class="hyper" style="fill-opacity: 1e-06;">...</text> is not clickable

Answer (score 0):

this is how you should be able to identify SVG node and then sub nodes of that.

```
//*[local-name() = 'svg']
```

Comment: @Ashvin this will only identify svg node, the same way you need to identify child node.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code   

 driver.findElement(By.id("rfb")).click();
```

Comment: Could you please provide link of the website you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

try using class attribute of the button using CSS Selectors:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-primary")).click()
```